# Rundeck broken after upgrade from 3.3.8 to 4.10

Tags: exception, upgrade, liquibase, rundeck

My Rundeck ran fine on **3.3.8** for ages until I ran a "yum update all" the other day. It seems that yum updating tried to upgrade the Rundeck to **4.10**:`Packages Altered: Updated rundeck-3.3.8.20210111-1.noarch  @bintray--rundeck-rundeck-rpm Update          4.10.0.20230213-1.noarch @rundeck`

After that, I cannot browse to the rundeck portal anymore. The service is still running though. Looked up the rundeck.log and found the errors like these:
`ERROR boot.SpringApplication [main] - Application run failed liquibase.exception.LiquibaseException: liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set core/ConstraintsIndexesKeys.groovy::3.4.0-56::rundeckuser (generated): Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: (conn=6) Can't write; duplicate key in table '#sql-b34_6' [Failed SQL: (1022) ALTER TABLE rundeck.scheduled_execution_filter ADD CONSTRAINT FK22545y15qs4iqod1ljyqsm1fi FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES rundeck.rduser (id)]`

What would be my best option next? Please help.

Thank you very much!

Looked up rundeck.log for the errors.

Comment: What backend are you using? Following this: https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/upgrading/upgrading-to-rundeck-3.4.html#db-migration  go to the `rundeck-config.properties` file (on `/etc/rundeck` path),  use `dataSource.dbCreate=none` instead of `dataSource.dbCreate=update` and restart the service. Another solution could be back up your projects and start a fresh 4.10.1 instance (with a fresh backend), the gap between 3.3.X and 4.10 is huge. Greetings.

Comment: @MegaDrive68k Thank you! I tried the 1st way but it did not work. Fortunately I have   a snapshot of the disk which I used to revert my changes. I will look into the gradual upgrades of the rundeck next.

Comment: That sounds better, please LMK.